# accelerate MySQL query

Tags: mysql

This is the shortversion of my query:

```
SELECT product.* FROM product_list product
LEFT JOIN language_item language ON (product.title=language.languageVariable)
WHERE language.languageID = 1
ORDER BY language.languageValue ASC
```

When I use it, the query has 3 seconds. When I remove the order by the query has 0.3 seconds. Can you recommend a change to accelerate it?

`product.title` and `language.languageVariable` is a language variable like global.product.title1, and `languageValue` is the title like car, doll or something else.

```
CREATE TABLE `language_item` (
  `languageItemID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `languageID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `languageVariable` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `languageValue` mediumtext NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `language_item`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`languageItemID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `languageVariable` (`languageVariable`,`languageID`),
  ADD KEY `languageValue` (`languageValue`(300));

id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys                              | key              | key_len | ref              | rows | filtered | Extra 
 1 | SIMPLE      | product  | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY,inactive,archive,productCategoryID | NULL             | NULL    | NULL             | 1475 |    88.27 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
 1 | SIMPLE      | language | NULL       | ref  | languageVariable                           | languageVariable | 767     | db.product.title |  136 |     1.00 | Using index condition
```

Comment: any index on languagevalue?  (Show execution plans)

Comment: perhaps index the languageValue column?

Comment: add tables structures (`show create table`) and explain result (`explain your query`)

Comment: This is an INNER JOIN. Just sayin'. Maybe the short version's too short!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - SELECT + JOIN + ORDER BY performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305324/mysql-select-join-order-by-performance)

Answer (score 0):

TRy this:

```
SELECT d.* from (
  SELECT product.*, language.languageValue AS lv
  FROM product_list product
  JOIN language_item language ON (product.title=language.languageVariable)
  WHERE language.languageID = 1
) as d
ORDER BY d.lv ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. But now the query has longer

Comment: Ok please Post the EXPLAIN of York Quere

Comment: See my answer bevore yours

Answer (score 0):

Here is the structur from language_item with the index:

```
CREATE TABLE `language_item` (
  `languageItemID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `languageID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `languageVariable` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `languageValue` mediumtext NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `language_item`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`languageItemID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `languageVariable` (`languageVariable`,`languageID`),
  ADD KEY `languageValue` (`languageValue`(300));
```

The Explain:

> id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key |
>   key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra  1 | SIMPLE | product | NULL |
>   ALL | PRIMARY,inactive,archive,productCategoryID | NULL | NULL | NULL
>   | 1475  | 88.27 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 1 |
>   SIMPLE | language | NULL | ref | languageVariable | languageVariable |
>   767 | db.product.title | 136 | 1.00 | Using index condition

Comment: You can delete this now.